# Learning german

Tags: learning

I need to learn German, but I can't study it in a school or so. And my internet connection don't allow me to use online methods. Is there some books, with audio tapes avaible that you would recommend me ? My mother language is French, but a english-to-german method would suits me. 
Any other tips on how to learn it in fast way would be welcome.
I already work with German speaking people but they uses dialects.
I do not need to speak nor write it perfectly.

What I already do is listening to the german FM radio anytimes I can.

Comment: I just realised the fact that reading q/a on here teach alot

Comment: Lots of different suggestions here: [What is a good way to start learning German?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/what-is-a-good-way-to-start-learning-german)

Comment: @Math Welcome to the German Language SE. If you want, you can take the [tour] or take a look at the [help]. On a personal note, I'd like to know, if that's OK with you, why you need to learn german, and why you need to learn it fast. Business? Love interest? I'm curious :) Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu  no problem :)  I come from Brussels and I recently moved near Germany so everyone here speaks German. I already love that place. I first where thinking 'got whole life to learn German' as ppl here are open-minded but in some month I will be a daddy and I need to be able to help my kidwith home works etc :) Let's say that I have lots of reason, but they all came togheter !  And yes, being able to speak with my coworkers would be nice. I don't want to be the "french one"  for ever ;) "Eine andalouse cheeseburger öhne salat bitteschön"  ;p

Comment: @Math thanks and best of luck! Being a dad is wonderful, but the homeworks are a bit off yet, no? :) Anyways, feel free to stick around the site, there's lots to learn, even for the natives. You might also want to take a look at our [chat], where some learners show up from time to time as well, with specific questions too soft for the main site, or just for friendly chatter and live practice.

Comment: I will for sure come here and read stuffs on spare time and maybe ask some question. See you :)